# Resample to 12bit PCM sound?

Tags: audio, pcm, sampling

I have trouble finding a program wich will resample 16bit 44.1KHz PCM into 12bit 25Khz. There's not much info on this to be found...

Anyone have a clue? I tried audacity, ffmpeg,... but to no avail. I was thinking about reducing the amplitude on a 16bit sample by 75% in a normal editor and throw away the highest nibble but something tells me it might not be that simple...

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using Audacity, but it's not so intuitive. There is no direct resampling option, so you need to do it in two steps.

In the Audio Track menu you can use Set Rate to change the samling rate to 25000 Hz.

That only changes the replay speed, so you need to resample it also. That is done with Change Speed in the Effect menu. The speed change is 44100/25000 = 1.764, which is 76.4% faster.

Now you can export the track to the 12-bit format that you want.

Comment: It indeed sounds like this could do the trick, thanks. I might use these two modifications in ffmpeg and be able to make a drag-drop converter in php..

Answer (score 1):

I found another way in the meantime; sox (the command line version) - very good and complete conversion: http://sox.sourceforge.net/ I am converting the sample rate with sox and process the raw file through php